# Two colors in a div element

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm trying to color a div element in two colors.
I want, that the color of the header is other than the colour of the body. The body has the color class blue or green (depending on the use case - angular HTML code).

**My problem:**
If I define background-color: x for the class header, then there is a rectangle that doesn`t fit the borders of the parent. Any ideas on how to solve that?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="parent (+ class blue or green - depends on use case)">
<div class="header">
</div>
<div class="body">
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
 .parent{
 border-radius: 20px;
 padding: 12px;
 overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
 .date {
     font-size: 13px;
}
 .blue{
     background-color: darkslateblue;
     box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgb(52, 41, 119);
}
 .green{
     background-color: darkolivegreen;
     box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgb(100, 120, 60);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.parent {
  border-radius: 20px;
  background: olive;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: white;
}

.header {
  background: red;
  padding: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.body {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="header">The Header</div>
  <div class="body"> The body content</div>
</div>
```